# Square of a polynomial has non negative coefficients implies that the polynomial has non negative coefficients?

Tags: polynomials

Let $f$ be a $n$ variate homogeneous polynomial with real coefficients. Suppose $f^2$ has non negative coefficients, does it imply that $f$ also has non negative coefficients?

Comment: What about $(-x)$ or $(-x-y)$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Or, more complicated but maybe what OP had in mind, $x^6+x^5+x^4-x^3+x^2+x+1$.